# How to initialize Swiper.JS in Elementor Pro dynamically with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor, swiper.js

I'm building simple one page layout website with Elementor Pro and Hello Theme. I have an issue. On section on the website is build with 3 columns layout. On desktop it look nice, but on mobile devices I rather would like to show this section as slider. What I found is that Elementor uses SwiperJS for slider. Here is the code I've got to turn into slider on mobile:

```
<section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-53777fe3 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="53777fe3" data-element_type="section" id="summary">
    <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
         <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-145d728 animated bounceInLeft" data-id="145d728" data-element_type="column" data-settings="{&quot;animation&quot;:&quot;bounceInLeft&quot;}">( content of column/slide )</div>
         <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-4c151e67 animated bounceInLeft" data-id="4c151e67" data-element_type="column" data-settings="{&quot;animation&quot;:&quot;bounceInLeft&quot;}">( content od column/slide )</div>
         <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-53280d85 animated bounceInLeft" data-id="53280d85" data-element_type="column" data-settings="{&quot;animation&quot;:&quot;bounceInLeft&quot;}"></div>              
    </div>
</section>
```

As you can see I added id #summary to section. Then I created custom js and css files and upload them manualy.

custom.js:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('#summary', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slideClass: 'elementor-column',
    wrapperClass: 'elementor-container',
    breakpoints: {
        640: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 40,
        },
        1024: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 0,
        },
    }
});
```

custom.css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #summary .elementor-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #summary .elementor-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        display: flex;
        transition-property: transform;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    #summary .elementor-container .elementor-column {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        transition-property: transform;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Then I modified functions.php and load my files:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/js/custom.js' ), ['jquery', 'swiper'], '', true );
wp_enqueue_style('custom', get_template_directory_uri('custom.css'));
```

So I thought everything looks good. The effect?

1. My files custom.js and custom.css are properly loaded.
2. swiper.js is laoded before custom.js.
3. section tag has new classes .swiper-container-initialized and .swiper-container-horizontal
4. First div tag with elementor-column class has new class .swiper-slide-active
5. Second div tag with elementor-column class has new class .swiper-slide-next

So Swiper propely initialized, but still on mobile device there are all 3 elements visible and no slider.

Please help me with this issue.

Kind regards,
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

Hide that section on mobile, add slider widget, hide it for desktop and only show on mobile.